# error CS0151: A switch expression of type `method group' cannot be converted to an integral type, bool, char, string, enum or nullable type

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Please help me on using switch statements on monodevelop for Unity3d. I've already searched details on how to correctly use `switch` statements but even so, I'm getting an error about the 'method group'. I still don't get what I'm doing wrong.

my class for accepting values for `info_check`:

```
public int check (int info_check)
{
    return info_check;  
}

void onGUI()
{
    switch(check)
    {
        case 1: 
            whatishiv();
            break;
        case 2:
            preventhiv(); 
            break;
        default:
            whatishiv();
            break;
    }
}
```

My class passing values for `info_check`:

```
nurse_class db;
db = transform.GetComponent<nurse_class> ();
if(GUILayout.Button ("What is HIV?"))
{
    db.check(1);
}
if(GUILayout.Button ("How to prevent HIV?"))
{
    db.check(2);
}
```

Comment: I don't see that you would initialized check variable anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean? Should I go and use "public int check = 0"?

Comment: Your check method doesn't do anything except of returning it's parameter !?

Answer (score 3):

`check` is a method. When a parameter is declared for a method, the parameter should have a value associated with it but you called the method without sending parameter to it. You should call it like this:`check(an integer number)`:

```
void onGUI()
{
   switch(check(1))
   {
      case 1: 
          whatishiv();
          break;
      case 2: 
          preventhiv(); 
          break;
      default:
          whatishiv();
          break;
   }
}
```

Although Your `check` method is redundant because it doesn't do anything except of returning it's parameter!

Answer (score 1):

From $8.7.2 The switch statement of C# 5.0 spec;

> The governing type of a switch statement is established by the switch
>   expression.
>
> • If the type of the switch expression is sbyte, byte, short, ushort,
>   int, uint, long, ulong, bool, char, string, or an enum-type, or if it
>   is the nullable type corresponding to one of these types, then that is
>   the governing type of the switch statement.
>
> • Otherwise, exactly one user-defined implicit conversion (§6.4) must
>   exist from the type of the switch expression to one of the following
>   possible governing types: sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long,
>   ulong, char, string, or,  a nullable type corresponding to one of
>   those types.
>
> • **Otherwise, if no such implicit conversion exists, or if more than
>   one such implicit conversion exists, a compile-time error occurs.**

But in your case, you try to *just* put your method name in this expression part. That's why you get this error.

Instead of that, you can call your method with any integer value on switch statement like;

```
switch(check(5))
{
    // your cases
}
```

By the way, since your `check` method returns it's parameter value without doing *anything*, I would delete this method and call this switch statement directly with a constant value.

```
switch(5)
{
    // your cases
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use

```
void onGUI()
{
    switch(info_check)
    {
    case 1: whatishiv();
        break;
    case 2: preventhiv(); 
        break;
    default:whatishiv();
        break;
    }

}
```